# Valor mínimo de columnas y filas de una tabla en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Quiero encontrar el valor mínimo  así como este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba intentando este método para hallar el valor mínimo en la fila, pero no he podido:

```html
let obj = [
{ 1: 47, 2: 89, 3: 9, 4:23},
{ 1: 97, 2: 1, 3: 30, 4:53},
{ 1: 40, 2: 25, 56: 19, 4:41},
];

let minimo = obj.map((a, b) => {
  
    let aa = Object.values(a)
    let bb = Math.min(...aa)
  
    for (const key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key))
       b[key] = bb;
    }

    return a;
  
  
  }, {});

obj.push(minimo);

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para añadir un item al final de cada objeto de la cadena con el mínimo y un array al final con los minimos por columna.

```js
let obj = [
    { 1: 47, 2: 89, 3: 9, 4: 23 },
    { 1: 97, 2: 1, 3: 30, 4: 53 },
    { 1: 40, 2: 25, 3: 19, 4: 41 }
];
let minCols = []
obj.map((c,i) => {
    let fila = Object.values(c)
    let min = Math.min(...fila)
    obj[i]['min'] = min;
    for (let x = 0; x < fila.length; x++) {
        if(!minCols[x] || fila[x] < minCols[x]) minCols[x] = fila[x];
    }
})

obj.push(minCols);

console.log(obj)
```

Si quisieras un objeto con la última columna el `for()` cambiaría un poco.

```js
let obj = [
    { 1: 47, 2: 89, 3: 9, 4: 23 },
    { 1: 97, 2: 1, 3: 30, 4: 53 },
    { 1: 40, 2: 25, 3: 19, 4: 41 }
];
let minCols = {}
obj.map((c,i) => {
    let fila = Object.values(c)
    let min = Math.min(...fila)
    obj[i]['min'] = min;
    for (let x = 0; x < fila.length; x++) {
        if(!minCols[(x+1).toString()] || fila[x] < minCols[(x+1).toString()]) minCols[(x+1).toString()] = fila[x];
    }
})

obj.push(minCols);

console.log(obj)
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

EDITADO: en el array de objetos que tienes que usa como ejemplo tienes un número raro en una Key `{ 1: 40, 2: 25, **56**: 19, 4:41}`. No afecta a la función solo es por matizar.